# Choosing distinct ID with differing column values

Tags: sql-server

Lets say I have this query:

```
SELECT id, date, amount, cancelled
FROM transactions
```

Which gives me the following results:

```
id  date     amount   cancelled
1   01/2019  25.10    0
1   02/2019  19.55    1
1   06/2019  20.33    0
2   10/2019  11.00    0
```

If there are duplicate IDs, how can I get the one with the latest date?  So it would look like this:

```
id  date     amount   cancelled
1   06/2019  20.33    0
2   10/2019  11.00    0
```

Comment: What is the data type of the column date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is with [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) and a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) like this example. In a multi-statement batch, be mindful to [terminate the preceding statement with a semi-colon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql) to avoid parsing errors.

```
WITH data_with_date_sequence AS (
    SELECT
          id
        , date
        , amount
        , cancelled
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS seq
    FROM dbo.SomeTable
)
SELECT
      id
    , date
    , amount
    , cancelled
FROM data_with_date_sequence
WHERE seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to use `ROW_NUMBER` function, which will group rows by id and order them by date within same id.

```
;WITH max_dates AS (
SELECT id, 
    , date
    , amount
    , cancelled
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS Position
FROM transactions
)

SELECT * FROM max_dates WHERE Position = 1
```